# Migration too slow

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm faced with a problem. I'm a user on SO and [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com). So quite often I get a question there that is much better asked at crypto or security (and I should be qualified to judge on the topic by now).

The problem is that if I flag a moderator and indicate that it should be migrated that the time it costs to migrate the Q/A can be measured in days, if not weeks. Obviously, a user cannot or won't wait for that long. Furthermore, if I notify the user that I've flagged it for migration and nothing happens then the user will cross-post, blame me that the question is not migrated.

So I am left with several options:

1. ask the user to delete the question and ask it on the other site

   - users get pretty pissed off if you ask them to delete a question
   - the user has to manually copy the question to the other site
2. just answer the question and flag

   - I'm answering an off topic question
   - my answer has a big advantage over other answers from the other site
   - other answers may not be forthcoming for days/weeks
3. just close the question as off topic (and possibly ask the user to post elsewhere)

   - the user does not get an answer at all
   - it usually takes a long time to close (because of the off-topic queue and the fact that [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) and [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption) are not followed by many)
   - the chance of it being migrated is non-existent
   - the chance of cross posting is very significant
   - the chance of the answers on the cross post being aggregated is minimal

So can anybody give me hints on how to proceed on such questions?

---

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432073/is-it-safe-to-use-private-key-encryption-for-lots-of-small-blocks-of-data-themse/26439584#26439584 (asked for migration to crypto or security)

[EDIT] Hah, yes, that one got migrated immediately of course (I hope not because it was featured here), but:

- [(Bigish source code) Beginners Java project, lots of problems, has to do with encrypting alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26189346/589259) was from 4 Oktober, and it is now the 18th (asked for migration to codereview)

---

**As the stackexchange network now consists of many sites with gray areas and overlap. The number of related sites will only increase with time. This means that it should handle migrations gracefully. Currently this is not the case.**

Comment: I'm posting here since many other sites have a much quicker moderation system due to the amount of users. On crypto there is not much of a queue for anything.

Comment: And if it really belongs on meta.SE I dare you to try and migrate :P

Comment: You are making a pretty strong case for the crypto beta to be terminated and merged into SO.  The [cryptography] tag on SO looks alive and well.

Comment: Why do you think your 2nd example is off-topic?  Looks on-topic for SO, which hurts its viablity for migration

Comment: @psubsee2003 No, it's not on topic. It's about unnamed programming mistakes in a bunch of code. There is nothing for other persons to search for. On review the answer could be used as a good example of a Ceasar cipher though, so I guess it would be on topic there.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not making that case at all, it would pretty much kill the crypto site. Questions there are completely off topic on SO. Just because there are questions here that belong to site X does not make site X redundant.

Comment: @psubsee2003 And even if the request for migration is not correct, the question is still in limbo - it's not clear if it will be migrated.

Comment: @owlstead I'll admit it's not a great Stack Overflow question, and  I'm not a member of crypto, but why would a "fix my code" question be on-topic on Crytpo?  The value of the answer is irrelevant.  If you want to post that answer on Crypto, then ask your own question about the topic and post it as an answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, sorry, I'll clarify; I asked for migration to code-review for that one, not to crypto.

Comment: @owlstead my mistake then.... that would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 4):

Don't answer questions on Stack Overflow that need to be migrated to another site. Leave a comment for the OP to delete their question and post it on the appropriate site instead. (Or tell them to search around and see if the question has already been answered. Moderators are often reluctant to migrate questions because we don't want to create duplicates on the target site.)

If a question has an upvoted or accepted answer the OP *can't* delete it, and migration is the only option. It doesn't matter if the OP gets pissed off that you suggested they delete their question and move it. They asked an off-topic question, so educating them on the correct site to post it on is the right course of action. Waiting on moderators to migrate a question for them doesn't give them that immediate feedback.

Comment: Usually the moderators on the other side are much more competent with regards to identifying dupes. And if the user asks the same question on the other side then I presume they would be stuck with the same dupe. Dupes are not always bad, haven't we just changed the SO method of handling dupes?

Comment: Just to understand, what should I do: ask the user to delete & vote to close + indicate the other site to the user? That's three steps, and I have to *hope* that the question is not answered on two sites in the mean time.

Comment: @owlstead The burden of identifying dupes shouldn't be on moderators on either site. The OP should be doing that, and part of that process is finding the right site to ask on.

Comment: @owlstead Yes, vote to close as off-topic and comment for the OP to delete and repost. It doesn't matter that it's three steps. It doesn't need to be a smooth process. Migration is easy, but it causes other problems, so taking the time to educate users on the correct process is worth the effort.

Comment: Yeah, but currently if I ask to delete I can get into lengthy discussions with users where they "ask" for clarification. Sometimes that leads to moderator attention as well. I'm of course with you with regards of protecting the mods, it's not like they've got time to spare on SO. For now I'll try and see if I can get users to delete, but I've had some pretty bad experiences with it (not that I lose sleep over it, but still).